# What are the first lines in ClearCase registries?

Tags: clearcase

I'm migrating some vobs from a server to other server. I have seen at the start of the registry files this information:

```
-id=34f9591e.96994cf7.99b9.b6:2e:6e:0d:fe:d9
-dtm=153ae31e.3cec4c29.9bc4.45:3b:24:08:e0:0a  
-version=3
```

Somebody can tell me what are these lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of the exact meaning behind those lines, but I have done enough migration to tell you that you don't need to report those lines from one vob registry server to the next:

You only need to register again your vobs once migrated and available in their new vob storage path (as mentioned in "[Moving VOBs and relocating VOB data](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_relo_mv.htm?lang=en)").

The two first line *should* be specific to the registry server, in order for ClearCase to manage different registry server, and for [`rgy_switchover`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/rgy_switchover.htm) to work properly (between primary and backup registry server host).